# Bad Ptr when passing string reference as argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, cuda

I've been trying to understand why the following code gives me a bad pointer on the string 'filename':

```
Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags) { 
    // some code returning a Mat object 
}

int main() {
    string s = "test.jpg";
    imread(s, 0);
}
```

I've debugged step-by-step and all I've got was that before entering `imread`, the string was fine (I was able to inspect each element of it), but afterwards it was impossible to do so, and the debugger accused a Bad Ptr. I'm not sure I understand why that happens.

Just so you know, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and OpenCV 2.2.

EDIT: I have indeed forgotten to say one important thing, that was essential for me to solve this issue: I was writing this code on a .cu file, therefore being compiled by nvcc in a first instance.

Comment: "gives me a bad pointer"? The code you've posted is fine (aside from the undeclared `Mat` and lack of a return statement), so the issue (whatever that is.. you don't actually say) is elsewhere. Can you post a minimal, complete testcase that demonstrates the issue? Or at least some output from your debugger?

Comment: opencv already has an `imread` function, why do you try to redefine it?

Comment: @Nawaz: well, I use OpenCV GPU, but I don't actively create any other threads on the CPU.

Comment: @etarion: the imread I wrote here actually is the imread of OpenCV. I just wrote the header of the function so people that are not familiar with OpenCV would understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Tomalak: sorry if I wasn't clear, but the issue is that somehow the reference to the string is not the same before and after entering the method, for the debugger accuses a 'bad pointer', which means it is referencing something that is not what I meant for it to reference.

Mat is a class defined elsewhere and my comment inside the function says "some code that returns a Mat object", so it is assumed that in the real code there is a return statement. :)

Comment: @Renan: Again, the code you posted is fine. References are safe. You have some memory corruption somewhere and we cannot possibly tell what that is from what you've provided.

Comment: @Tomalak: I did another test. Instead of creating a string and passing it as argument, I passed a constant char array ("test.jpg"). Following step by step with the debugger I found that the string after the function call was "t.jpg". Somehow the pointer to the beginning of the string shifted. Does it matter if I tell you that imread is in a DLL?

Comment: @Renan: You have some memory corruption somewhere and we cannot possibly tell what that is, from what you've provided.

Comment: I just experienced the same problem with imread. When I compile the with the Debug configuration, the filename shows as a valid string and everything works fine. When I compile with the Release configuration and step into imread, filename shows as <Bad Ptr>. I went into the Release configuration and turned off optimization. I recompiled and stepped into imread. This time the pointer was good but the string showed some ASCII gobbledygook, so clearly it was not pointing to the right thing. I am running VS 2010, OpenCV 2.3.1, Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by separating in different files all OpenCV code from the code that involved the CUDA extension. Therefore, imread was now being called from a .cpp file and everything that involved CUDA was on different .cu and .h files.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this is supposed to be that way, maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Writing debuggers for native code is a non-trivial task. There is no 1 to 1 correspondence of the machine code to the source code. It's common for the debuggers to give such misleading information, it doesn't mean though that the actual value is invalid. Also make sure that you compile with debug info turned on and all optimization turned off.

Note: when you step into a function, the stack-frame may not be initialized yet. Doing one more step may show the correct parameters.